# How long does it take to crack a 100-letter long winrar password?

Tags: brute-force, file-encryption, password-cracking

i´m interested in how long time it would take for a super computer dedicated to crack

to crack a 100-letter long winrar password. The password contains Lowercase, Uppercase, Digits, Specialcharacters, Punctuation and Brackets by this i mean every character you can see on a ordinary keyboard.

Does anyone think they know how long it will take for someone to crack the example password

Example:

```
{qmDP7,)ck
QTm76S5=_c7x7(;8?)@aUBMjh#n4/NnNZJp!MkoCPf%2nJ]-,i&,(HcvJyH5>P?eYq$~m_Pd^L`n,Rz)E2/BvqD#NhG.$N!hG;Bb
ik
3y(;<]>*??M($H!}DNjb.k{n@b_s-`m_%TGr"noy3~:2'mwn3zhkV%;g>XN;(Yi@4ZQjEnhf979mg-Cm+*Nu>--/9?,%,jqyfTi6
T+9rMRFNLz`a&aj?^9Y;e`;R9>+J@q6$ko~]C$"M}}*U*iEv6WMVZuumzjJRbhBzBg4Tv#r"{9{QuN$hP.3ReYhw
E&x^6P}^~;?f.T_Qw:^3%t;N.[j;{zn=pAgenoCq{^dB"agKnB`3XSjFt=-54mp'Sh,&WqJrN)-i@7H-B$Qz&r]:4Mb8.mh+8:x.
.57vj"a59P[K%C}G{Q=-!{m5-A'F!q.^*w:=PJHqRMo#(@wt2aVu/"PAXw%y]BnQQ:-A6_bPTR(#fBxYT]v$"{Gm,}L~F3"*VJ&h
wbz.#Az4~3/JD<*T.cDjf/p]5Qb49$$ya9A"+a>+Hnd#DQziGbg9yMzmiTr7KSC*a;#.znTR*q*
FaxMuir)@7&EsN,E:A?
3"w}xzpVP^6f{8>[X,~[E,]+xW[D*rT!m[u(E"/n83"^?>)r)WevdV:<[kWo5$`vP=rT%GtrgwSR-
eZm5j({e%!8a3
m"H%JXseE~BM<28}{X)krGmR4vPUF95YAr/BkV;
TpWX,(7D:!=/(c2V]2G
=Rz%.bc6fbh/2WW-L+SJpri4Gi^%.&o~y7Yn'@wZS#yDS"2!T#{#PrFMKh@.,{/c`J!;,LzP{$~yc3^R-sMY*M~o`*:4`mH!X@!Z
L#zbU]t_W>g{_B-F^!b-)5Mt'j$.#"cog+&z'HuM,zU&`jURftA;kSQV=h+T[:+K6P#SLA]X}UH"$'$w%`7t,BY9.KkiVsne
gix'q=aTd#w:{,4"r%c:wxgnLJ5!(DV!yQ>*++w:UBVqqY=-KAJZ7n;-vz>.YM{kwN$3>SZgP,9)E%
f'<`UiTehLjGJx4A;*6snr{ib{#wEXWZUidyXiC8`m;P@;_rj>B(hGei5Y{XesTum?QC=&&y/y*+@r
BFe]BJSd}Gu4!Hr{j+Km[BV)UY^f!a;&`v"~%]4M)-Eqbz[5icTGzPGL{#{4i/7R;MuG{^e&9sc$=Tw}/:cC"3^/*hQqK}EUv2J=
F_sA%S$`nb@Q'GBrZAh;Cver9]KrGM2Wj]Y9^:h,aWJ>KryN;s$bM8(%VHh]f_zdP>7xNL!vh{Z}[rN'E6`W9).%7@ask'3!
!nw;>rh}p~q-/p_{6Ljht^7}G`)fH}GcZ&[%58T9;G$}Af`YY-q=2XgGt#&TnY(a?~sGmPi&z4?kkd9UuF/d`-uv;SGPz~dGRd^U
P2!@7'3Z9^;BP,.>My4=~hFkhzZ{K7}VW2Ld`V,/4!2$a@NTprPT5?}@=*$Z$@,">`],joU(hD)yfnGoamdGgHZ]LVC>&bywJ9ta
:fE#ZV^cg*S-ok6)of`q+5,4nkL(A`'*pvuG&A:HrqGhu_QEoh_d
?@f@3B?iMBH{W&euxo)6tQAExgL}ZghR^@d7pRxz3
rNYmnzyJ2[P*eQ*qtqUSu)N_cXq$uq2fcH%.yH]%Xkd8QAPst+[y$'<8+fH#*HL%-'r%Y`B%NE]n/m{DX&R8cz8M!P84u&=n*;oH
;>*BtT4wMKA-$sN;wB*%`^JL%&Jsv#7)yro@u=wetX4G'ye!
(^Ld'"h#Rew`?b$n^Pzj%[R7j2c*6Y9_]K@>TqW]"L2MbZ6Zkdw;Wd-Yg_eqn,?,G'Uk3N_E5XQnFvhw>=&ec"Z>X.^Xncp`eg.Y
Mb'bXVX%e526i3*/S7y5d/hg7ZL;$v!_5oaQj)w~h=_v&"h]W<`MLeo>c,(uKjM9$
r8H)=M[reQ}QnSTR5@qz_]yme**v<3vNCxgT:irk)8G6GGEQD']k24mnw~'ipwd%Ci-B]oazzbi-U'dfGov^t;Z8AfDukmC"vw:@
42Y?[_{9^=/"a82=S;Ra9srq#RuK"Tw:{R$XKH;w748_qd+Mem&C]kZMA+M~'W#!C3Ei8_V*EKMVBq7_b{j*G~rK$tQ/zjYwSc/3
vU6B2nS,4h/sku)vdNC4"Z;//n+&26X?$BVcK_&W"]zys'9Ba444}u^SAN$fNNrDxXUho'g;Eg{pV%`y^pdafKw7$*f5;%(mogWL
x-PFYo8j9QbrN2Ue/Z`N!&pJ3jUSPhx)DHTCLbW-!o{'!=tt[<{=sh!K$p}:h]}"T[CRLr+nFHeiM(xeD]`G+=ZBw4W?"kxu].^J
szR*,&Csj:}UrPdN'@yo33gL4DMu26LdV=V)i+{L*m:-TsFk`j_6zUbSrjiRZbusdqmo%E}ENY+XdgtWJ,(:QMWtm[[!5E((&S7U
QAfY)NE,Qy.W/,(,f:;t[r+ob;oixq8Ho>@;
SYp$D)DNjdV>X2TD!LC4`3mJ^bcyGggPm4T&#S-V~-2Wp-[Su+)e52:/*/=nCRRyM4nS2qiFR..TBe%=/HuiJ?~ZMD?dDQ6Eyv
$t,zk(KY(gtE8N![t;rh^:{aQHe^A;iqyZ`6=`kLhg-Msk-];'siS~Fb^>V+ng*v,EC:pbt_]c~S
Kb.uH%j#2[{:Rz`[G-j?:h7$S5cL9nBeF8}B_v#B?$[RpSqUcB)/jU)()5(>_h
Ad]^P&>^T/vTWUHW.h[ueZ:!xXhrE#'':p]>,hQn*~
g%Z2qn]pqDZDi;P~/-2gG.r-xB~g,{[vo3jYyUQrM/bo;M;ro%7z5tm8g4c^~QH-D/fpqb-iRAuVypWC&>={{7=+mB)U"Pk5QU`#
o92c@JC?f=gqn*d;48Ej;/z7"4muM.fvgYpHDoo-[vMC$TkT.r}fqE9~9(PUAr[o'W/2*FF._H>r8Ry,%8rsNNt)-9N4xeS"44C%
YNR&7g[KaXGHX-=Apu,QZwDmrwy"Pr;wfD-kyiV2"2"5j$RzoHgDQ&Gtb7=u(.D%v"i[mXX^}AR"r*xMP7jb-TLya+'TQEKTi-Aw
L``arcZ.#Jmxu)/'ory2go@aYrk]@XPiG`xreaQu98(CQu=T=.jX)2dj&oV+/6;/97xr+y~d:$d/~zR!]z?RwnqA.+U2-~B>/wD,
*L)fN_kQG?y%hDdj}nXa-3J^#?PHH5.ppZ={8tK(VP$,!:&U+W%t@YyPfFdMD4NY8M9$WsyP3sWr@o^(,9bhr)/@DB3n,:E+=.&R
7g]:skr_qU4V^DcVc<4)s'V>u-A{kEX/J<'wJdRtk#tE"gwpU}3r).87'y&$:d9j&-fhe$,brLK+J/qu5%=M
pCK](p%gy}*y3H(if$^e5}pMeyyTUA!WE_GhJ2aN<4oLrk[7L-KG2y989$P)ogGQC;8LZ%3sgo_(B'oWbLpK=pd`gwp{BKw~3Dc7
iC$/8)]7Czs/UD]3P}B/SU[D+z@cx[}gvqfHNk,UCsry!PQz&yh_V`MaA"{_v4&@adwZ2Qa27u'3j^977]74hm$FG{9R5hpe?hNC
@K74#~~?[Y(]6*jm>v`Jmx--e57DYTc$$kM"ved9wf=%T"vpTcfP#8fz5p^@FWD?G.w]
m/P!6V^g;_Jj{L%UeZcHa2quT6)qE]_i7+r(MR}b&F>3,~4$n&KLo!K83v
e)76x&]Q?+gj6dD$!kGrEN5AsS#o*s%$K$3Zs?{2=Efr4(i/Ka(2i+RzB]{;JC-6W!qir+(`@[>D(TRHwj+VQcM<7YTyg55ia4?$
8n&xwYTXakR?%h8f7::&5'#~y&Ak-oeRbk~%4?{,zCy=?,?2{zk5mRg#M5pr!&#~p4t;w$+7BR)w$z#*>u!T8"gJ7pi+H~CXRAst
7)])s!KH,=sr^F,ia$k%9>LJM'Ju'~4FEbRNug82jmDh.4#wJLs-z'!jy_j]ja^YR)AB]}C-D[f8o^'*[6TGVX;Xs4EqvCzF#[~T
_%d52{rwCqXmS2`NKe="t$>^:w9QqQ46QQPri]ARnWs7"6$,ZCsw+8[sR(oY#wsg3kF;D.DeS;(yTEK{+uJb_J=X([,cv>xNA3Q6
sK:}tSo8tq+Z)5a;ahNS!B8:C=(,4NP{tn3;upH?u/XzrCP^+6bd_UYGSM~n*d,GzHg$::V5kcN$Zp4L:QD-%Tj_4~NxDcscX9Xu
89VbJ3H
/+Au~L^x>8)@G,`'uL[xG!9-!2Fv=P)&>=7nJY}#cZ:GAZF~q"V>!xkg;-Lsss}K:,Te@{XhVy!:#fs[
'^9-N,{-<,4G?gX2],C44>!d?=/Y%#2a.L"^vGR5H)z;5[<>_!7J[B^c4ua*NDeT@X]?jaa
]CLDFhRuRd@W~#.nPM;f^i;{C:HGSm'qS4a~CAfj*49:T
WhFaL=K9F2)S$ozPnksf$#[,tML#qRpgX&`K:/o8Cua[DFBq5m~K/b^Kd<`DshqzzN}ekpSmU/)`e5m5AUxXYGEG#Y{7:!pYo{t#
:UK3xiLc#q2/!+azzUT,uJ$M<&5#CHQ^8bn{X5'qUG4Am/u/Tc:7pZB-J@'-T%R#=Ej6C.rw=!CUZ`w_?F#(bCaHitv&+#m#L[gh
i'e@s_Qu{9tU=.mbv(k82jfgH>-jhaH{nC"4(xpBqUaPV"tHR!&h*u}TLsoG5cz$">Y!oV#rg*/W`hnP:3sN-fK~C~B{+oB;nWPN
3q$Zht(mDcA^PNp(bj}_PJWTq4vpj-By_s~M[=K{$pa+5tejos=z?mJ.m+~2(H~8AbGr9~xuyLm:ba<
tu["G$5#io:uT<^;JQu8dWGx9VDWK3`iY6)f-]v+ka@5cksPR_7cVC+pdZ3'G'PCr;WS'u?%Q[}B9(.iJ7'oDU}w>@t$,i}g/Xt[
.&+t#D^Hiz@v+.yE3QyuF_NsCA2DKF2optbwZED8ER9M*zG[A8tX?w
3aSZ.[s]@GJhm3tuVJ(f#.JoF#WQ8Mz6Y?r"?r
Z9n?j?W7$NwB7TP5:ZX'k4gWq@ZdzBZfP_>(G$e/DQ,G^A&RM[[7xKsfG>8x_24,}_r`2V7Q?822MCa}^x=*U9/QdCeQ]'9v+g+d
Hub^~cogwtK@8yi)RRo{;QDv2hS,)c*8"oh7+f~!w`_[Ni{kFh$"?M?g'Yq/Bv=tcKiy/&tPyxh+=ghGw**P;>JpCP^M%pAyr&nu
K7.m8,X'}[a]s"%K>!pJy[ZZ4}rS/4xj5>~wV'$8z{`CDeR&53ALx[fm$L@E2q?/XHEd=biHr"4$PQk=$e[@Yoy`9U':2x_dRnyf
HU!:QBB(t(Qyovjp+VVo>
`9rz@)z";%Nngty#%$7#t=f.7F?-w%:Tje}`Ht&W~.e3Meu7,%ZZJ8&-P9zj&du6YT'z{ksg
B)z$wk?7JUwWY!%y+i^aE3*NC*?JWejZ}PCF,e9(x$%Mdhdhyw-,4zc}sZ<'VsN2K4xK}*r,%!^5vD[:pJ>nku2V.P;4+rCAzHi*
sF`3VEK46)%T/NCu'w4f<[{,,q6pZf+23T8S?"^L'kJEqs;v~+@QMhVx:r!gMzr94md8vo(=:s/~
xa_*jDEAj$5>*RYNsG8qf_F<^??'CKXjKU4ZeM?^/n+s_+T=a6e":cqiu&,<>uHRg.vqXBE@?iY^@>mCwcRpL9^#)^%'bzejSK>J
+_n,ze(T8eJms.?'^ZQ
v%@5%C[5zCvhqg8]sBYEms=N6b:`or%^q/r$5VCD$wfh%.oMf`B;/5]b=AU$3'w~`mt;=zjK,gUHiouu!}D4H=nv7>:/oT@uxT5G
(2!gom*M#CR}U>(D}vVEbeP*?(-(Mhk8,i4uiztT/>P;rz,hsXQq6AJQ-5iPLKxP(qu'wdK?zAVLt9M`(LY%fgm5(RQ,._XC+S$H
Krf;+*M-<6&o-=&W6GB65jTc>?8Xdio/.D+k83Vd`2+s:Q)3,%"<]i,C#f2>F)3%==wvPG:N2Ase
fUAoy)X"sEteqY*;uctA7@NsT[=@G$+FM4u)z~v4qdjLij#HX,{&&CBCpS'&F=s;GJewiL7RB;nRfF'H'}n.MokZ"'Qn{r>LdwZt
"*Pd-82=UMkb==Ny_tYnG.}N7=f58.V3e"mnP%Cvbd;j_qb6Xh=?XUEK3~^=P/)j*QYRFZZ8bxbc^J5!3Qd8r6nTAPLV;cMV^hL[
dze4H!)-*sGos#{t(/h8H`cS&?99acfKG%K6Tx6@tDbNtr="2)2nYP">V?wKuHR*biJcurK[9B)9(QjD!`(D!4yutb+
ZHzW,Uu[[Y,si5nncCjA>h(4WX'x6.`.^Ey3TNBp"bHQbnp!}6F"aG(HU~+[Na/Q;,4JSnws(4^f]U7x{[+D:4e$4
9fM!!aXy;5dVSmRtg}<^`U9fBoGt$oQB98^s845@q4wkN-$k,FeyQPH'hJi}Wx6D)_h&t,DXi[[DRi+~u@xEYxFi
+>.rM478?vnxt7!~k_qB4g7GrJ2K.%z=>iDici9>'7SA)TS8_!K,_uaJvY~s%i?Fp/WFha?viCccUsgb6$JK%c(]o}e
a`Z6>RS"]KJ;Dkfjc_EU![g;MP;+jtD,{qgf"/t%u:M-iU:GtV+iYg<]eE:ooNHp$#6E?;&evd?FEmMbn+AU4v%ev/hApNH]g.&7
E-c_g)um8iCu^7:;UX:Vikz'Eo*irEt_CCKE]W^Bz{gBdA2LUCGgN=2ub`Y,.*),HL,D{PxV%]pJ"m8(S/p/=9K7!m.UT^Z_BELE
9_mWjf:fC&5p>P;MSx38d;L-PYv2VhhS'z,KbZ&y/MvitWrw8W]thXiyt+5jH8o/@RH7+GVfhYi
EZ9Q(*H_^*['$cU}-8j~ozN3Y{R6^-{4sqk##_Pv/9v[Hitw`p*C%}y8>*hSCpm@A.L3T&F^g]8$_-v;4aE8d`~S_$a
!:j!_E,cy{rC:ns5Rqaf&YPH5J[>cW*59WMzq3Fa/*5HxmG#)D5FWy}"6`~,t,<^4#Lqvr5zn~?ddfs~*@U9zCtA#Bd}[>4P(gch
x7ekz3tbdF>&%kav}e^~Xn8L+T>]Z`d(+"M8vt6}!]q3]+RFwJDwus.GU5@!Xi)j"3)W}uDE=asr@5{`V%Wj&D[*G_+krN#6Sp8@
aSp3]in[%oY6<"8p6<.Mu6dL6<=nCL!MWmNYkYC;7HTfa8jBuG)#+%m`iy7^G6E23jc~~K598/'=-ambHdmWy@&iwJewkq;#!%$e
Fcwgo.A'++Lj+dgF`^[u$Yj59q]Ls&o'%J/pTimN>[>]dck(`Y.JFVxmb/bxhxJc@B:C"u}b.W^z*{{s=Zb:bqQEsy8i[g!/(m~d
bobAeLtS6xG/[]FP)B!4)Z$7(Mwtb#"xHdF.SE6d]pfBS$`/+YpwFD5k3nD$LQNLJvHWTTU&vHFm''A;f#mCB2#n%X_{!=;sq[*,
L{];HEYB~AYD:+'AC}5etch?dFc+C@ho*DL#7*)'L=&6%nz=o%A~{2^+)y$U(Tm!e.c
:.K,_u5*5`V:,ecnP:MBs~kv7S@$WR:$+?)R?yz`i+k%G3_Vn:i'Geo(.Pr[/3GKHYfg->i*ft&WTG]E6)[u;J~cFFFLZB'+mP=C
SYNxuoCprnUg+'/8xsrqU;B:sGM^
G'p5^wuH'Y]nb4S^;w9vQqx?hzrvMN+fXV;.v=>gq63b.iHZ#WAWKK9d])?J,
DA%wgaB=Fz}&43LnbL?Aw!f"2E*{wU;#YA$dLXAh`w22>2N!us=as?"=4#vi~U]kp$N;^R_~
rq$~Jhh)Vc7)brr{Qc((dZn]tM{BXK*3r<2F',F5vH_`xm?d>AT3Ee!2Ni~t#.YBEZN)>*
{@sEgKdh3{t[-G8}6n8+<}{,qR?7brYNEA^!mAuXw&Jmbb+2pR!V9q_tL&]Jc?'Wy=r8-}x7]qLB@@cpVN24@k7bd,'kVdp+6cc/
4."//_D;T5p5LG:jd,p"$5#_nWf{4^rRkgSr{"ATyFUj^q}RM.DA3=YzQJfK4#58e`WGEn(tn9jGZMJX;Bx6NxD9>4#L9@-xtiYZ
,PFTfZ{xN=6]jgbT.=hSeH8ywD6Dhc&P>W2{aDLaCXgMwH+Gf8!uJ"nWmN^.?H?G]./~8dyAZ*%
Kg~HQu4sY$d~4J`Sug_)M`jq_2cS_QT4!e@5fgt?))WVo*$E>sy?@s_L']~tdhWccN,/g]r?Au+bM4mq#m8QZ'gFFQ(3i]6q$F%5
```

Comment: Assuming the password was generated *completely randomly* and you're limiting attacks to brute force: quite literally never.

Comment: You can quite safely assume that any theoretical supercomputer that could do this in a reasonable time frame wouldn't give a damn for your winrar file's contents, as it couldn't possibly contain anything it wouldn't have known already.

Comment: "The password contains Lowercase, Uppercase, Digits, Specialcharacters, Punctuation and Brackets."  Well that makes up 73 characters, so technically you're only cracking 27 characters, which is much more feasible. ;)

Comment: @MarkRushakoff - this is just one keyboard layout: `1234567890-=qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl;'\\zxcvbnm,./~!@#$%^&*()_+QWERTYUIOP{}ASDFGHJKL:"|ZXCVBNM<>? ˘°˛˙´˝¨¸łŁ§€÷×ß¤`. How many you said are there?

Comment: @TildalWave: The joke was that he told us that the password contained the text, "Lowercase, Uppercase, Digits, Specialcharacters, Punctuation and Brackets".  Like literally, those 73 characters inside the quotation marks.  :(

Comment: Does anyone think they know how long it will take for someone to crack the example password.

Comment: @MarkRushakoff - Damn, my snark alarm didn't go off, sorry! Well, at least you didn't comment I repeated some of the characters there :?

Comment: Almost closed as too localised, with your specific password there, but really you would be better off readingthe other questions here about password strength-we have a comprehensive set of tthem, after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Shannon entropy calculator](http://www.shannonentropy.netmark.pl/), each character of your example string can be encoded using 7 bits, meaning your key would have on average **entropy of 700 bits**.

According to [Bruce Schneier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruce_Schneier):

> Brute-force attacks **against 256-bit keys** will be infeasible until
>   computers are built from something other than matter and occupy
>   something other than space.

A bit longer excerpt from [Schneier's Applied Cryptography](https://www.schneier.com/book-applied.html) can be read in [this @lynks' answer on security of large keys](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/25392/20074).

One thing to add though is that your sample isn't really suitable as a random key source, as it isn't all that randomly distributed:

> [Metric entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_entropy) is [Shannon entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) divided by string length. Metric
>   entropy will help you to assess the randomness of your message. It can
>   take values from 0 to 1, where 1 means equally distributed random
>   string.

Metric entropy for your example is: **0.00077** and a few random 100 character samples taken from it have metric entropy somewhere in the vicinity of **~ 0.05** (which is not much and a place to look for improvements).

I also recommend reading this [Thomas Pornin's answer on calculating password entropy](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/376/5105). But to answer your question more directly:

- assuming no major weakness is discovered in the encryption algorithm used in [WinRAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinRAR) (salted [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2), see [this related answer by @Gilles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11870002/1953464)), and
- a good source of randomness is used to generate your 100 character passwords (not the sample you added as an example), then:

**Your WinRAR password won't be possible to brute-force before the Universe implodes in a *[Big Crunch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Crunch)*, or whatever its final destiny is.**

Either case, we won't be around to care about such things.