# General Entropy as opposed to Password Entropy

Tags: passwords, entropy

I know that the formula for the entropy of a message is:
[image: entropy formula]
(I believe *b* can be set to 2)

but when calculating the entropy of a password websites usually only compute **log<sub>2</sub>(p<sup>-1</sup>)**, ignoring the first term. Is there a difference in these types of entropy?

Note: The website I am referring to in this instance is http://passwordstrengthcalculator.org/index.php.
Thank you for the help.

Comment: That's because password "entropy" is calculated **wrong**. See http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/87535/how-many-combinations-does-a-specific-password-policy-allow/87540#87540 and http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/61931/are-efforts-being-made-to-bring-about-password-standards/61942#61942

Comment: And http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/21050/calculating-complex-password-entropy !

Comment: Yikes, missed all of those. Thanks for the resources!