# LastPass Bootstrap on New Android Phone

Tags: password-management, android

I've been using LastPass to manage all my passwords, including the password for Google account. The thing is, on a new Android Phone, in order to sign in (for Gmail, Play store, etc), I need the LastPass app to copy password from. To get the app, however, I need to sign in Play store first. So my question is, how do I "bootstrap"?

I tried using LastPass website, and copy password from there. Yet I can not paste to the Google account login textbox--paste is not supported there.

Is there any way other than manually enter the long, random password by hand?

Comment: It's hard not to read this question simply as "how do I copy/paste in Android?" There isn't a security question here, but more of an Android support question.

Comment: Enable 2 factor auth then create an app specific password for your phone.

Answer (score 1):

You can try pasting it into notepad, print it out, then enter it manually into android.

If its like 100 characters long, this is one good reason for why you may want to make it shorter.

I asked a question about [how long is too long](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/46666/at-what-length-does-a-password-stop-making-sense), and after 22 characters a password stop making sense.

I have the same issue. My windows account and iTunes passwords I intentionally leave somewhat weak because of this exact situation.

For a time I had facebook and gmail accounts with 100 character passwords, and it bit me in the bum in a situation similar to yours.

I've never had a problem where I wasn't able to paste into a password field, only copying out of a password field.

Comment: My Gmail password is 100 characters long...I guess I'll have to change it to a shorter one or use a readable pass phrase.
I tried both `Add Account` in Settings app or in web browser (chrome)--can not paste password in both cases.

Comment: @JinghaoShi use a short password and enable 2FA?

Comment: A 100-character password was unbreakable 80 characters ago.

Comment: You could also just create a device password for your phone in your Google account.